# filter:grayscale(0) animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I'm using the jQuery plugin [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) to animate a set of images when a user scrolls over them. The effect I want to achieve is that when the user scrolls over the said images the following css gets appended to the object - `opacity:1` and `filter:grayscale(0)`, `-webkit-filter:grayscale(0)` and `-moz-filter:grayscale(0)`

The `opacity:1` works fine when it's on it's own and the opacity effect is achieved successfully. However, I can't seem to get `filter:grayscale(0)`, `-webkit-filter:grayscale(0)`and `-moz-filter:grayscale(0)` to work. here's what I'm using. I'm sure it's a trivial solution, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

```
/* Waypoints
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* set-defaults
------------------------- */
    $.fn.waypoint.defaults = {
    context: window,
    continuous: true,
    enabled: true,
    horizontal: false,
    offset: 0,
    triggerOnce: true
    }

/* #about-section-two
------------------------- */
    $('#about-section-two').waypoint(function() {
    $('.avatar' ).delay(0).animate({opacity: 1, filter: "grayscale(0)", -webkit-filter: "grayscale(0)", -moz-filter: "grayscale(0)"});
}, { offset: '50%' });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Ian

Comment: First: `grayscale(0)` doesn't do anything. You need `grayscale(100%)`. Also: What browser are you using? According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/filter only the webkit browsers currently support it - and despite that my current Chrome doesn't display it.

Comment: When I set `grayscale(0)` on a `:hover` event in CSS it works just fine - I'm using latest stable version of Chrome. However, regardless, it isn't even showing up in the HTML inspector - `opacity:1` is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's simply a case of jQuery `.animate` not supporting all CSS properties. Anyone who may be interested may refer to [a list of supported properties](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp).

Comment: If you're using a new feature like filters, why not take advantage of animating them using CSS transitions. Filters are transitionable. See http://codepen.io/imakewebthings/pen/ynGaB

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing... But I needed the transition to happen only when the user scrolls onto a specific div which is achieved via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is no animate in jQuery for filter grayscale yet. You can wait until it comes or use this script (only javascript, no JQuery):

```
function grayscale(div,millisec,bool){
    if (bool){ /* We want to become grayscale */
        var i = 0;
        timertogray = setInterval(function addgray(){   
            if (i < 101){
                document.getElementById(div).style.filter = "grayscale(" + i + "%)"; 
                i = i + 10;
            }else{
                 clearinterval(timertogray); /* once the grayscale is 100%, we stop timer */
            }
        }, millisec);
    }else{ /* We want to give color back */
        var i = 100;
        timerfromgray = setInterval(function addgray(){ 
            if (i > 0){
                document.getElementById(div).style.filter = "grayscale(" + i + "%)"; 
                i = i - 10;
            }else{
                clearinterval(timerfromgray); /* once the grayscale is 0%, we stop timer */
            }
        }, millisec);
    }
}
```

And call it with :

```
grayscale('Content',100,true);  /* Activate grayscale */

grayscale('Content',100,false); /* Give color back */
```